# how to seperate a signal into 4 second segment using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have an ECG signal and I want to separate it 4 second segments. How to do it in MATLAB?

```
% MATLAB Code

load ('C:\Users\Explorer\Documents\MATLAB\PhysioNet_Database\Malignant_Ventricular_Ectopy_Database\418m.mat');

signal=val(1,:);

plot(signal); xlabel('Time'); ylabel('Voltage');
```

[418m.mat](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D543B6FF876DF180!166&authkey=!AHBBGhL4OdzHZ5Y&ithint=file%2Cmat)

The signal is downloaded from website of PhysioNet and is of MIT BIH Malignant_Ventricular_Ectopy_Database.

There are two signal in 418m.mat. I just want to separate first one signal.

Also, there is a function buffer() in MATLAB but it is only for equally spaced in time. I don't know whether this signal is equally spaced in time or not.

Comment: When you know the sampling frequency resp. sampling interval you can calculate the number of samples you need for a 4 second interval and use this number for splitting up your signal.

Comment: You could try (disclaimer: I wrote it)  `rollstat.m`  , http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52553-rollstat--y--window--slide-funin-      That function lets you define the time window and groups data items by the window rather than the number of elements.  It's not exactly designed for splitting a vector but you should be able to adapt it.

Comment: @ Matthias W. J

Thank you!